# URL with two parameters

Tags: laravel, url

I want to generate URL with two parameters. In my `web.php` I created a route:

```
Route::get('/pojedinacni-turnir/{godina}/kolo/{kolo}', [
  'uses' => 'Frontend\PojedinacniTurnirController@show',
  'as' => 'pojedinacni.turnir',
]);
```

where are my two parameters are `godina` and `kolo`.

In my Controller I create show function with two parameters: id from godina and id from kolo.
Here is code from my controller:

```
<?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;

  use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use App\Sezona;
  use App\TurnirPojedinacni;

  class PojedinacniTurnirController extends Controller
  {
   public function show($id_sezona, $id_kolo)
   {
    $sezone = Sezona::orderBy('godina', 'desc')->get();

    $sezona = Sezona::findOrFail($id_sezona);

    $kola = TurnirPojedinacni::where('sezona_id', $id_sezona)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();

    $kolo = TurnirPojedinacni::findOrFail($id_kolo);

    return view('frontend.pojedinacni_turnir', compact('sezone', 'sezona', 'kola', 'kolo'))->render();
   }
  }
```

When I try to check my URL i get this message:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: pojedinacni.turnir] [URI: pojedinacni-turnir/{godina}/kolo/{kolo}]. (View: C:\WebSites\TkPazin\TK_Pazin\resources\views\frontend\pojedinacni_turnir.blade.php)

I don't understand error because i try URL with two parameters. I created URL with id's that exist like this:

```
{{ route('pojedinacni.turnir', ['godina' => 1, 'kolo' => 1]) }}
```

and even then i get the same error message.

*Update: added blade file*

```
@extends('layouts.frontend')
@section('title', 'TK Pazin | Pojedinačni turnir')
@section('css')
 <link href="/css/style_pojedinacni_turniri.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
@endsection
@section('content')
 <!-- Page Content -->
 <div class="container">
 <!-- Page Heading -->
  <h1 class="my-4" style="text-align:center; color: #ba3631;">Pojedinačni turniri {{ $sezona->godina }}</h1>
  <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        @foreach($sezone as $sezona)
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ route('pojedinacni.turnir', $sezona->id) }}">{{ $sezona->godina }}</a></li>
        @endforeach
    </ol>    
</nav>
<div class="row mb-5">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-2 mb-5">
        <div class="list-group">
            @foreach($kola as $kolo)
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">{{ $kolo->naziv }}</button>
            @endforeach    
        </div>
    </div>

 </div>
 </div>
 <!-- /.container -->
@endsection
```

Comment: What's {godina} and where are you getting it?

Comment: {godina} is ID from Sezona model.

Comment: Let' s have it this way. Godina is ID from my table years. Kolo is ID from my table Tournament. Between this two tables we have One to Many relationship (One year can have many tournaments). I want to create a view where i can see tournaments in specific year. That's the reason why I need to get two parameters. One for year and one for tournament.

Comment: As the message says, the problem is in your Blade template, not your controller.  If the IDs exist or not in your DB does not matter - you would see a different error if they didn't exist, not this one.  Somewhere in that Blade file you are generating this route without the parameters.  Double check *that* code, and show us.

Comment: At the end of my post is the example how i generate url. For purposes of testing I made it statical i will make it later dynamical

Comment: Added blade file to question

Comment: So now it is clear right?  The `route()` in your Blade is **not** like the example `route` you showed first.  `route('pojedinacni.turnir', $sezona->id)` is missing the 2nd parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You blade file shows that you have only added 1 parameter

```
@foreach($sezone as $sezona)
     <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ route('pojedinacni.turnir', $sezona->id) }}">{{ $sezona->godina }}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

Add the additional parameter

```
<a href="{{ route('pojedinacni.turnir', ['godina' => 1, 'kolo' => 1]) }}">{{ $sezona->godina }}</a>
```